# Querying and Parsing a table data from a website aspx

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-apps

I'm new to coding.I need your help desperately

I have a requirement to gather farm produce data from the below website.
http://agmarknet.dac.gov.in/PriceTrends/SA_Month_PriMar.aspx

Need to gather the data from tables displayed in this website and store in google spreadsheet.And this should happen automatically evryday after 8 PM.

Thank u ..﻿

Comment: do you want to gather the data from the website or the database ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to extract data from Website not database...I'll not sure what libraries/function to use in Google script to load the data into google spreadsheet